# Show one screen, hide another?

Tags: display, appletv

I'm a teacher, and I like to cast my laptop screen to the television in my classroom via Apple TV.  However, there are times I'd like my students to see one screen while I work on a different one they cannot see.

I don't have multiple monitors.  I know there is a way to do this but can't figure it out!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for info on asking questions here.  Please [edit] your question to include the device and operating system you're using to in conjunction with the ATV as well as how you're sending that display to the ATV (mirroring, AirPlay, etc).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you using an Apple laptop, i.e., MacBook/MacBook Air/MacBook Pro? If yes, what is the version of macOS running on it. If no, what type of laptop are you using?

Comment: You mean, you want to freeze the Television in your classroom to a specific image meanwhile you work on something you don't want to show to students?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution assumes that you are using a Mac running OS X Mavericks, and is connected to the same Wi-Fi network as your Apple TV.

You can use the Apple TV as a secondary display over AirPlay. Go to System Preferences → Displays, and select your Apple TV under AirPlay Display.

[image]

You can both mirror the contents of your Mac, or use Apple TV as a second display (your desired use case).

Go to Arrangements under Display preferences and uncheck Mirror Displays to use Apple TV as an extended display.

[image]